# Snowflake Data Type Conversion

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am getting a conversion error as explained below:

1. Created an insert into a Table using SHA1. The filed is binary
2. When I try to query the table with this field, I get an error shown below.

Do I need to convert binary datatype to Varhcar for querying?

Cannot convert parameter ''D832F2E3518C72414C9FAC5131951F3DADCBG51A'' of type [VARCHAR(40)] into expected type [BINARY(8388608)]

```js
insert into test
select SHA1(concat(EMPNAME,'|',ETYPE))  Field1
from "TABLE1
select * from Table1 where     Field1 ='D832F2E3518C72414C9FAC5131951F3DADCBG51A'
```

Answer (score 1):

> *Do I need to convert binary datatype to Varhcar for querying?*

Rather string literal to binary:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Field1 ='D832F2E3518C72414C9FAC5131951F3DADCBG51A'::BINARY
```

---

An open question is why Field1 column is BINARY when SHA1 returns VARCHAR.

> [SHA1](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/sha1.html)
>
> **The data type of the output is string (VARCHAR) and can be stored in a VARCHAR column:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE table1(Field1 VARCHAR)
AS 
SELECT SHA1(concat(EMPNAME,'|',ETYPE))  Field1
FROM (SELECT 'a' AS EMPNAME, 1 AS ETYPE) s;

SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Field1 ='469f9400148c19c663c1aa53ca53cbf9f2526ea6';
```

---

> *My question is why SHA1 returns Binary?*

It returns VARCHAR(40) as stated in documentation. But during insert there is implicit conversion to Binary as Field1 is defined as BINARY.

```
select SHA1(concat(EMPNAME,'|',ETYPE))  Field1
from (SELECT 'a' AS EMPNAME, 1 AS ETYPE) s;

DESCRIBE RESULT LAST_QUERY_ID();
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the update. My question is why SHA1 returns Binary?

Comment: It doesn't. When you insert into BINARY column you are performing implicit conversion.

Comment: in that case should I have my target column as Varchar or perform conversion at insert time so that binary values are preserved? Please advise